# python isinstance is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

This is my code

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    print 'process_spider_output'
    for r in result:
        print 'r type = {0}'.format(type(r))
        if isinstance(r, Request):
            key = self._get_key(r)
            if self.db.has_key(key):
                spider.log("Ignoring already visited: %s" % r, level=log.INFO)
                print 'Ignoring already visited: {0}'.format(r)
                continue
        elif isinstance(r, FlexibleItem):
            key = self._get_key(response.request)
            self.db[key] = str(time.time())
            spider.log("Writing to log: %s" % key, level=log.INFO)
            print 'Writing to log {0}'.format(s)
        yield r
```

I am trying to print the type of `r` and the results on my cmd are:

`r type = <class 'TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem.FlexibleItem'>`

**So the type is FlexibleItem**

but why the second condition is never becomes true? I have never seen the printing statement from the second condition

#### Edit

This image for the kindly user who is helping me now.

[image]

Comment: Can you please the definition of `FlexibleItem`?

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry I didn't understand your question, what do you want me to show?

Comment: where you are doing `print 'r type = {0}'.format(type(r))` do `print r.__class__.__module__, FlexibleItem.__module__` and see if they are the same.

Comment: @warwaruk I will do that and tell you the results, wait please

Comment: @warwaruk the result is `TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem` exactly the same

Comment: @warwaruk did you mean that I type `1/0` after the printing statment in the `elif` ?

Comment: also, after `print 'r type = {0}'.format(type(r))` do `if  r.__class__.__module__ == FlexibleItem.__module__: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Then you will be dropped into debugger, where you can test `if isinstance(r, FlexibleItem)`

Comment: @warwaruk I will do that and tell you what happened

Comment: @warwaruk it seems the the debugger is opened now. what should I do to walk line by line please?

Comment: type `isinstance(r, FlexibleItem)`. If you type `help` and press Enter - you will be shown the list of debugger commands. Typing `help n` will show you help on `n` command.

Comment: @warwaruk I got `True`,

Comment: Type `n` and press Enter.

Comment: @warwaruk I got results, please check my question, i added the image

Comment: @warwaruk I mean that the image I added is what I got after typing `n` then pressing enter

Comment: enter `n` again. if it goes into `if isinstance(r, Request):` branch, enter `isinstance(r, Request), isinstance(r, FlexibleItem)`. If noth are true - here is your problem. If it goes into `elif isinstance(r, FlexibleItem):` branch, enter `n` until it goes to the `print` line.

Comment: @warwaruk you are the GOD of the python bty. it goes to the second condition, then when it trys to print , the problem shows, THERE IS NO `s`, looooooooooooooooooool, I should have said `key` instead

Comment: Welcome to the `pdb` world! It dramatically changed by debugging and development! See also [`ipdb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)

Comment: @warwaruk write and answer to accept it please. I apprecite your help alot alot alot. The problem in this question solved, I will write another question today and I will invite you to it. 1000000 Thanks

Comment: @warwaruk would you write any answer please my friend

Comment: @warwaruk I want to thank you again. you are great. Big respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case it's either what Ignacio said, or the problem was described incorrectly.

> but why the second condition is never becomes true? I have never seen
>   the printing statement from the second condition

Are you sure the second condition never becomes true? Put `1/0` right after `elif isinstance(r, FlexibleItem):` to be sure about it.

In any case a much better way to find out what is happening is to use a debugger. Putting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the first `if` will allow to run the script step by step and see what is happening.

Comment: please check my question stackoverflow.com/questions/22595578/scrapy-set-the-log-file-in-the-script

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. `FlexibleItem` is not actually `TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem.FlexibleItem`. Make sure that there aren't two ways to import the name.
2. `TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem.FlexibleItem` is a descendent of `Request`. If this is the case then the `if` statement will be true and the `elif` statement will never be evaluated.

Comment: none of the mentioned possibilities is true, I will explain. First, I have just one FlexibleItem in my whole project. actually It is my only class in my project. Secondly, There are a `Request` types ofc, but also, as I mentioned in the question, the cmd told me that there are `FlexibleItem` types

Comment: I count 2 `FlexibleItem`s. One is `TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem.FlexibleItem`. The other is `TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem`. And my second point stands, regardless of what type it is.

Comment: They are the same one. I have a spiders folder, which has the `__init__.py` and inside that folder I have `FlexibleItem.py`, and inside the `FlexibleItem.py`, I declare my class `FlexibleItem`. Thus, they are the same

Comment: No, one is a module and one is a type defined within that module. They are two distinct objects.

Comment: For your second point, the FlexibleItem is from Item, which is from DictItem, which is from BaseItem, which is from object_ref. So, 100% not Request.

Comment: So, where is the wrong? I make this `from TestSpider.spiders.FlexibleItem import FlexibleItem` and then, I make this `elif isinstance(r, FlexibleItem):`

Comment: Does anything blow up if you run it with `python -tt`?

Comment: I am using scrapy, as I mentioned in the question. To run the spiders, you have to do this: `scrapy crawl SPIDERNAME` on the cmd. Also, I add this parameter `-s LOG_FILE=test.log` in order to make the log to my customized file

Comment: Do you only use spaces for your indentation?

Comment: Yes for sure, my project is completely working perfectly. Now, I am just telling the spider to not crawl the already-visited URLs. I can extract items from websites, write them to database and query them. So, 100% I am aware to spaces